# Openstreetmap Javascript script

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, openstreetmap

Is out there any good js light plugin to embed maps in web sites?

Somenthing like gmaps, i'm trying a jquery plugin seems toooo weight , too much kb.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/06/jquery-google-maps.html

Comment: nope andrea , i'm using openstreetmap cause gmaps has requests limit, can't use gmaps itself to create the map, thx anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/

is pretty much lightweight

there's also OpenLayers with more features

Comment: in addition you can make OpenLayers custom build
http://docs.openlayers.org/library/deploying.html

which will make you able to reduce size to only features which you are using